# How do I delay a block of code from running?

Tags: c#

This is filler because for some reason stack overflow does not want my post to be completely code, even though the question makes is all you need and I really don't know what else here so I'll just post the question now.

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to this code!");
        Console.WriteLine("do nothing for 5 seconds . . .");
        //I need to delay the following code
        Console.WriteLine("Which game would you like to play?");
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) - if I recall correctly.

Comment: That just delays the whole compilation, I need to delay the code. Why in god's name would you delay the compilation? @500-InternalServerError

Comment: No, it does not :)

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` might be the fastest way, and it would be fine for your console. But it would be a bad practise in other platforms. You could also use a timer variable and let it count down in real-time

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It really does. I put that exact code in (with a semicolon, of course) and it waited for 5 more seconds to compile, and ran ALL of the code at once.

Comment: @Vled there is no way whatsoever that correctly using Thread.Sleep() does what you claim it does. there just isn't. did you, by any chance, compile & run in one step, and add the sleep call over your first Console.WriteLine?

Comment: This is my exact code


```using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to this code!");
        Console.WriteLine("do nothing for 5 seconds . . .");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Which game would you like to play?");
    }
}```




Compilation time: 5.127 seconds.
and i apparently have no clue how to format code in comments
@FranzGleichmann

Comment: @Vled there is no way to format code in comments. you aren't supposed to put code in comments. also: where are you getting that compile time from? also: works on my machine.

Comment: It may look like it is the compile tim but it isn't. I assume you click on "Start" and you see the console after 5 seconds. Go to "Build" and build your application and you will see that it doesn't take 5 seconds to compile.

Comment: @Heslacher Im using dotnetfiddle, it shows the compilation time.

Comment: Just tried with dotnetfiddle, showing Compile: 1.016s and Execute: 5.017s just how it should be

Comment: @Heslacher Yes but I want the first code to run, and then the other code after the delay. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you mixed up the numbers on dotnetfiddle. And just keep in mind, that dotnetfiddle is just a "NET sandbox for developers to quickly try out code and share code snippets". It is just the wrong tool to see the correct results. `Thread.Sleep()` is the correct answer but you just can't see it in dotnetfiddle.

Comment: @Heslacher Alright, thanks. I can't currently download apps, don't ask, so what browser tools would you suggest I use?

Comment: Sorry, don't know

Answer (score 2):

You can use  Thread.Sleep(5000);

Comment: The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Try using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)`

Comment: That delays the whole compilation, not the code.